# If there is no row in database sum command return an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

An error is thrown when there is no data in data base while converting a string value into int.

```
try {

        SqlCommand cmdc = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Credited_amount) FROM IMS_Credit_Dir WHERE Credit_comp_id=1 AND Crdt_typ_id=1", con);
        string companya_credit_amount = null, comapnyb_credit_amount = null;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader drc = cmdc.ExecuteReader();

        if (drc.HasRows)
        {

            while (drc.Read())
            {
                companya_credit_amount = drc[0].ToString();
            }
            drc.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
        SqlCommand cmdcp = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Credited_amount) FROM IMS_Credit_Dir WHERE Credit_comp_id=2 AND Crdt_typ_id=1", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader drcp = cmdcp.ExecuteReader();
        if (drcp.HasRows)
        {

            while (drcp.Read())
            {
                companyb_credit_amount = drcp[0].ToString();
            }
            drcp.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            int companyA = 0,companyB=0;
            if (companya_credit_amount != "") { companyA = Convert.ToInt32(credit_amount.ToString()); }
            if (companyb_credit_amount != ""){ companyB = Convert.ToInt32(companyb_credit_amount); }
            int total = (companyA+companyB);
            count_total_lbl.Text = "Rs." + " " + total.ToString();
            count_comapnya_lbl.Text = "Rs." + " " + companya_credit_amount.ToString();
            count_companyb_lbl.Text ="Rs."+" "+ companyb_credit_amount.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { Label2.Text = ex.ToString(); }
```

If there is value its working fine.but when there is no value in data base there is an error msg.

System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: You need to check the null values on all nullable columns before converting into your desire data type.

Comment: Why don't you just initialize companya_credit_amount and companyb_credit_amount to "0" instead of null?

Comment: int total = (companyA+companyB); //here i am geting error on this line

Comment: Are you *sure* you get the error on that line? I highly doubt that particular line give you a FormatException, are you sure it is not the Convert.ToInt32 lines above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this

```
SELECT SUM(Credited_amount)
```

WITH

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Credited_amount),0)
```

Also find one confusing code while converting Credited amount values

```
if (companya_credit_amount != "") { companyA = Convert.ToInt32(credit_amount.ToString()); }
                                                         ---------^^^^^
if (companyb_credit_amount != ""){ companyB = Convert.ToInt32(companyb_credit_amount); }
```

I don't know about your business requirement but What i think Instead of using `credit_amount` value `companya_credit_amount` should be use to show value for `companyA` variable right?

Comment: yes i want to show the sum of amount . of a particular company

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) to check for null values
2. Create and destroy all your type instances that implement `IDisposable` in using blocks. This ensures that connections are always released and resources are cleaned up.
3. Do not use connections across a class. Create them when needed and then dispose of them. Sql Server will handle connection pooling.
4. Get the native types directly, not the string equivalent! See changes to [GetInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getint32(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ToString` on the data reader.
5. You should refactor this to use `SqlParameter`'s and make the retrieval statement generic OR get both SUM values in 1 sql call.
6. There is an `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` statement, if none of this code does anything if it is a postback then check at the top of the page and do not execute the sql statements if it is a postback. Otherwise the code is making (possibly) expensive sql calls for no reason.

---

```
try
{
    int companyA = 0,companyB=0;
    using(var con = new SqlConnection("connectionStringHere"))
    {
        con.Open();

        using(SqlCommand cmdc = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Credited_amount) FROM IMS_Credit_Dir WHERE Credit_comp_id=1 AND Crdt_typ_id=1", con))
        using(SqlDataReader drc = cmdc.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (drc.Read() && !drc.IsDBNull(0))
                companyA = drc.GetInt32(0);
        }

        using(SqlCommand cmdcp = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Credited_amount) FROM IMS_Credit_Dir WHERE Credit_comp_id=2 AND Crdt_typ_id=1", con))
        using(SqlDataReader drcp = cmdcp.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (drcp.Read() && !drcp.IsDBNull(0))
                companyB = drcp.GetIn32(0);
        }
    }

    // if you are not going to do anything with these values if its not a post back move the check to the top of the method
    // and then do not execute anything if it is a postback
    // ie:  // if (Page.IsPostBack) return;
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) 
    {
        int total = (companyA+companyB);
        count_total_lbl.Text = "Rs." + " " + total.ToString();
        count_comapnya_lbl.Text = "Rs." + " " + companyA.ToString();
        count_companyb_lbl.Text ="Rs."+" "+ companyB.ToString();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) { Label2.Text = ex.ToString(); }
```

Comment: while (drc.Read())
                {
                    companya_credit_amount = drc.IsDBNull(0) ? "0" : drc.GetString(0); //error line
                }
                drc.Close();
                con.Close();                                                                                  Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Comment: @ManoharKumar - did you read my answer? Do not use strings because you are working with numbers (ints). Use the native type (number), not strings. Its all there in bullet #4 and in the code I provided.

Comment: @ManoharKumar - one mistake, `GetInt` should have been `GetInt32`, the above code has been updated.

Comment: Error has been gone but value not seen in label. Output is 0. when i have some value in DB

Comment: @ManoharKumar - run the queries directly in  SSMS and see the output. If you use the code above as is the labels will populate. I can't guess as to what your version looks like now but you will have to step through it and debug your code. It might be you misplaced a `!` or are not checking `Read()` (to advance the data reader).

Answer (score 0):

You should do 2 things:

1. string companya_credit_amount = "", comapnyb_credit_amount = "";
2. Before assigning the value to these string variable you should check for db null as following:

   ```
   while (drc.Read())
   {
   companya_credit_amount = (drc[0] != DbNull.Value) ? drc[0].ToString() :    "" ;
   }
   ```

Similarely

```
    while (drcp.Read())
    {
       companyb_credit_amount = (drcp[0] != DbNull.Value) ? drcp[0].ToString() : "";
    }
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize credit_amount to empty and check if db value is null as shown below:

```
    try {
            companya_credit_amount = string.Empty;
            companyb_credit_amount = string.Empty;
            SqlCommand cmdc = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Credited_amount) FROM IMS_Credit_Dir WHERE Credit_comp_id=1 AND Crdt_typ_id=1", con);
        string companya_credit_amount = null, comapnyb_credit_amount = null;
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader drc = cmd

c.ExecuteReader();

    if (drc.HasRows)
    {

        while (drc.Read())
        {
            companya_credit_amount = drcp.IsDBNull(0)?string.Empty:Convert.ToString(drcp[0]);
        }
        drc.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    SqlCommand cmdcp = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(Credited_amount) FROM IMS_Credit_Dir WHERE Credit_comp_id=2 AND Crdt_typ_id=1", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader drcp = cmdcp.ExecuteReader();
    if (drcp.HasRows)
    {

        while (drcp.Read())
        {
            companyb_credit_amount = drcp.IsDBNull(0)?string.Empty:Convert.ToString(drcp[0]);
        }
        drcp.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        int companyA = 0,companyB=0;
        if (companya_credit_amount != "") { companyA = Convert.ToInt32(credit_amount.ToString()); }
        if (companyb_credit_amount != ""){ companyB = Convert.ToInt32(companyb_credit_amount); }
        int total = (companyA+companyB);
        count_total_lbl.Text = "Rs." + " " + total.ToString();
        count_comapnya_lbl.Text = "Rs." + " " + companya_credit_amount.ToString();
        count_companyb_lbl.Text ="Rs."+" "+ companyb_credit_amount.ToString();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) { Label2.Text = ex.ToString(); }
```